# sfdx force:source:push failing with error: Could not resolve list view column: OPPORTUNITY_SCORE

Tags: error, scratch-org, push, scratch-org-definition-file

I created a scratch org off one of my production dev hubs, and am trying to push my source code into it. The push fails with an error "Could not resolve list view column: OPPORTUNITY_SCORE".

I believe the issue is that my scratch org does NOT have Opportunity Scoring enabled in it. This feature is optional, and must be enabled via Setup > Einstein > Einstein Sales > Einstein Opportunity Scoring.  My scratch org has Einstein Sales, but does NOT have an option for Einstein Opportunity Scoring.

What Features / Settings values do I need to put in my project-scratch-def.json file to make Einstein Opportunity Scoring visible? Bonus Points for sharing the configuration settings that autoenable it when the scratch org is created! ;-)

For review, here is my current scratch org definition file:

```
{ 
  "orgName" : "BluVector", 
  "edition" : "Enterprise", 
  "adminEmail" : "jp_seabury@*******.com",
  "hasSampleData" : true,
  "features": [
    "Communities",
    "EnablePRM",
    "ForceComPlatform",
    "MarketingUser", 
    "ProcessBuilder",
    "SalesUser",
    "SalesCloudEinstein"
  ],
  "settings" : { 
    "communitiesSettings": { 
      "enableNetworksEnabled" : true, 
      "enableEnablePRM" : true },
    "enhancedNotesSettings" : { "enableEnhancedNotes" : true },
    "knowledgeSettings" : { "enableKnowledge" : true },
    "mobileSettings" : { "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2" : false }, 
    "opportunitySettings" : { "enableOpportunityTeam" : true },
    "pathAssistantSettings": { "pathAssistantEnabled" : true},
    "quoteSettings" : { "enableQuote" : true }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a metadata setting for it documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_opportunityscoresettings.htm)

For the opportunity Scoring to work it involves installing the **Sales Insights** Managed package.

At this point, this is not Source Tracked so scratch org settings will fail.

You can automate by first installing the package after scratch org creation

```
sfdx force:package:install -p 04t58000000SGw3
```

And then deploying the Metadata Settings for the Opportunity Scoring.

Overall multiple hops at this point to automate and not a pleasant experience.

Comment: I will report to the team that handles Source Tracking and Metadata about this unpleasant experience!